# Why this code gives unreadable first line?

Tags: c, arrays, split

This code reads file and split it lines into array in order to compare lines elements to each other.
The problem that it gives me as the first line

```
 )�H�       2382    2382
```

I think that the function `char **linecontent(char *line)` is the problem but I am new in C and I tried every possible solution and I have nothing.
I am very sorry for asking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** split(char string[],const char seps[])
{
  char ** res  = NULL;
  char *  p    = strtok(string, seps);
  int n_spaces = 0, i;
  while (p) {
    res = realloc(res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);
    if (res == NULL) {
      exit(-1); /* memory allocation failed */
    }
    res[n_spaces-1] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, seps);
  }
  res = realloc(res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
  res[n_spaces] = '\0';
  return res;
  free(res);
}

char** readfile(char *name, int *lsize)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char *result;
  char line[500];
  char *pline = NULL;
  char **lines = NULL;
  int i = 0; 
  int l = 0;

  fp = fopen(name, "r");
  while (fgets(line,500, fp)) {
    i++;

    pline = strdup(line);  

    lines = (char**)realloc(lines, sizeof (char**) * (++l));
    /* Add to lines */
    lines[l-1] = pline; 
    *lsize += 1;   
    pline = NULL; 
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return lines;
}

char** linecontent(char *line)
{
  char **linecont;          
  char hit[300];
  strncpy(hit, line, sizeof(hit) - 1);
  hit[sizeof(hit) - 1] = '\0';
  linecont = split(hit, "\t");
  return linecont;             
}

int main()
{
  char **lines = NULL;

  int lsize = 0;
  lines = readfile("TEMP", &lsize);
  int i = 0;

  while (i != lsize) {
    char **linecont1;
    char *thisline=lines[i]; 
    linecont1=linecontent(thisline);
    char *pname1 = linecont1[0];
    char *acc1 = linecont1[1];
    int start1 = atoi(linecont1[3]);
    int  miss1 = atoi(linecont1[4]); 
    printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", pname1, acc1, start1, start1);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] - you must include the *file* you're using here.

Comment: @kiner_shah-- `fgets()` is a Standard C function, while `getline()` is not (but it is POSIX). And `fgets()` is not deprecated as the title of the question you link to suggests (though `gets()` was deprecated in C99 and removed from C11). How is this helpful to OP?

Comment: Please include at least the first line of the file `TEMP` you're reading.

Comment: If you think `linecontent` is the problem, print `thisline` before you process it and see if that looks sane.

Comment: Looks like `linecontent` returns pointers to its local variable `hit`. Try `char *hit = strdup(line);` instead of lines 2,3,4 of `linecontent`.

Comment: Btw., in `split()`: `free(res);` comes after `return res;` and is unreachable.

Comment: Minor: Wrong type used in `lines = (char**)realloc(lines, sizeof (char**) * (++l));`  Should be `sizeof (char*)`, (one `*`) or even better: `l++; lines = realloc(lines, sizeof *lines *  l);`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  When calling `realloc()` assign to a `void *temp` variable, check that variable, and if not NULL, assign to the target variable.  Otherwise when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: when calling `strdup()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: most of the `readfile()` function can be greatly simplified by calling `getline()` rather than `fgets()`

Comment: these statements:  `int i = 0;` and `while (i != lsize) {` and `i++;`  would be much better, written as: `for( int i=0; i<lsize; i++ )`

Comment: regarding these  lines: `char hit[300];` and `strncpy(hit, line, sizeof(hit) - 1);` and `hit[sizeof(hit) - 1] = '\0';`  1) The function: `readfile()` allowed lines to be upto 500 characters, so `hit` should also be 500`  2) the call to `strncpy()` should use the actual length of the input line:  I.E. rather than `sizeof(hit)`  use `strlen(line)+1` 3) the call to `fgets()` already terminated the array of characters in `line`, so adding another NUL character is useless.  Infact, the call to `fgets()` also input any trailing '\n' so that char needs to be overlayed with '\0'

Comment: regarding: `res[n_spaces] = '\0';`  the 'res[]' is an array of pointers to character arrays.  This seems to be trying to set the last entry in that array to NULL.  so the statement should be: `res[n_spaces] = NULL;`

Comment: regarding: `while (i != lsize) {` the `split()` function properly terminated the array of pointers (lines) with a NULL entry, so this line would be better written as: `for( int i=0; lines[i]; i++ )`

Comment: the posted code contains LOTS of memory leaks.  In general, do not have the OS clean up after your code.  Rather pass all the allocated memory pointers to `free()` when done using them.

Comment: thank you all for all your concern I can not express my regards. I did  remove line 2,3 and 4 in linecontent and it worked and replace with   char *hit = strdup(line);